# MS Excel TRUE/FALSE Formula Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: excel, formula, evaluate

See formula in formula bar. I would expect this to return TRUE. Instead it returns FALSE.

Also see Formula Evaluation at stage before returning FALSE.

I am on Automatic Calculation.

I can't tell if it's a Formatting discrepancy. There are no apostrophes or spaces before or after the values.

Help needed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing a Text to a Number. The result will always be false. You can use the VALUE function, to convert the Text to a number. After that, you can compare both values.

Comment: Value formula works, thanks.
I thought pasting both items as Paste Value would work, but it doesn't. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below formula in order to covert what the cell has in to value:

`=VALUE(B2)=VALUE(C2)`